# Is selecting a css class from the root element better than writing the class name directly? which one loads faster?

Tags: html, css

What is the best approach to use CSS classes?

To include the complete element path from root/parent till the element:

```css
 main section.search .input-container .input-url-wrap .paste-btn {
 //style
}
```

or to just mention the class name:

```css
.paste-btn {
  //style
}
```

The HTML will be then:

```
<main>
    <section class="search">
      <div class="input-container">
        <div class="input-url-wrap">
          <i class="fa fa-clipboard paste-btn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
```

**CSS**

Comment: If you want it really fast, give it an ID and use that

Comment: By writing the full path you are inforcing the HTML elements to be in this order; otherwise, your class won't have an effect (Suitable for a predefined structure like Menus, DropDowns, Generic components). Whereas writing only the class name makes it re-useable. So, it is up to you

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations and best practices are considered off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @connexo I'm sorry I didn't know that, I'm new here. should it be on stackexchange?

Comment: Btw, don't apologize for your English. Good luck!

Comment: @aliazhar Currently there is no site that I am aware of on this network for which this type of question would be a good fit.

Comment: @SamySammour ok, thanks for the explanation and the edit of this question.